# SwiftUI navigationBarItems: 'cycle detected through attribute' error on device rotation

Tags: swift, xcode, screen-rotation, swiftui

I'm getting very strange error messages with Xcode 11.5. Having device rotation support enabled, I get a bunch of error messages telling me "=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute XY ===" when the app launched in portrait mode and the screen of the simulator gets rotated. It only occurs on the simulator and just with iPhones, not iPads. Also, if I remove "navigationBarItems" the error message doesn't appear. Additionally, the content on the screen looks off (only on the Simulator, again). If I rotate again, the content is as expected.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("SwiftUI")
                .navigationBarTitle("Welcome")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    Button("Help") {
                        print("Help tapped!")
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with Xcode 12 / iOS 14. As a workaround you can try to use stack navigation style for both orientations

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("SwiftUI")
                .navigationBarTitle("Welcome")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    Button("Help") {
                        print("Help tapped!")
                    }
            )
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())    // << here !!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, even with StackNavigationStyle the issue is still present. Maybe  Xcode is somehow corrupted for me?